# Scraping returning clipped content (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a set of URLs stored in a list and I want to make a script to collect Genius site lyrics and store them, each in a txt file.

I've already made this script, but for some reason the content returned isn't complete.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import time

urls = ['https://genius.com/The-Stooges-1969-lyrics','https://genius.com/The-Stooges-1970-lyrics',
        'https://genius.com/The-Rolling-Stones-19th-Nervous-Breakdown-lyrics','https://genius.com/Lil-Wayne-3-Peat-lyrics',
        'https://genius.com/RunDMC-30-Days-lyrics','https://genius.com/Bob-marley-and-the-wailers-four-hundred-years-lyrics',
        'https://genius.com/The-Clash-48-Hours-lyrics']

start = time()

for u in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, 'lxml')
    for tag in soup.select('div[class^="Lyrics__Container"], .song_body-lyrics p'):
        lyrics = tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
        if lyrics:
            with open("PATH\\"+str(urls.index(u))+".txt", 'w') as f: 
                f.write(lyrics)      

print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
```

See, for example, the lyrics of the song on the url: https://genius.com/Rundmc-30-days-lyrics.

Now see the return obtained:

> "[DMC] If you need a vacation, we can fly the world
> And you'll know I'll never look at another girl I'm a single-minded man, and my mind
> is set You're the lady of the '80s that I'm gonna get [Both] And if
> you find you don't like my ways Well, you can send me back in 30 days"

Somehow I can access the lyrics, but there seems to be something missing to make the script robust, because it cuts the content in certain situations.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be wrong?

Comment: it's hard to tell without replicatable code. Have you tried placing debug breakpoint on responses with clipped lyrics and investigate the html? or simply save them to file if you're don't have a debugger ready. Looks like genius.com is using some anti-bot protection - could be that it's not serving you full content as it suspects you of being a bot.

Comment: Hi, @Granitosaurus. The code above is all the script I made. If you feel comfortable, you can replicate it. I've already inspected the soup's content and I saw the lyrics. I don't know if it's something in my loop that might be generating this error or the selected tag (div) that doesn't match the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see why it's doing that, but might just be that the site renders differently at times. I made a few adjustments and so far haven't seen the issue. It's possibly from the way it's parsing the text then how you're writing to file, so I adjusted some of the indenting in the for loop in how it concatenates the strings:

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import time

urls = ['https://genius.com/The-Stooges-1969-lyrics','https://genius.com/The-Stooges-1970-lyrics',
        'https://genius.com/The-Rolling-Stones-19th-Nervous-Breakdown-lyrics','https://genius.com/Lil-Wayne-3-Peat-lyrics',
        'https://genius.com/RunDMC-30-Days-lyrics','https://genius.com/Bob-marley-and-the-wailers-four-hundred-years-lyrics',
        'https://genius.com/The-Clash-48-Hours-lyrics']


start = time()
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
for u in urls:
    response = requests.get(u, headers=headers)
    #print(response)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    
    lyrics = ''
    for tag in soup.find_all("div", {"class":re.compile(r'^Lyrics__Container')}):
        lyrics += tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n') + '\n'
    if lyrics:
        with open("D:/test/lyrics/"+str(urls.index(u))+".txt", 'w') as f: 
            f.write(lyrics)  
        #print(lyrics)

print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
```